# Children’s book about the child of a single parent who travels back in time and meets another child of a single parent

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

I’m looking for the name of a children’s book that would have been written before the 1970’s, 50’s or 60’s or possibly even earlier.

It’s about a child and a single parent who move into an old Victorian house and the child discovers a rift in time and goes back in time to discover another child with a single parent, a widower. The two children introduce the parents to each other, and the parents fall in love and they all stay in the past together. May or may not have a grandfather clock involved.

I thought it was called “A Stitch in Time” but can’t find a book with that plot. Does anyone know? It was my mother’s favorite book as a child, she did a school project on it in the 1960’s, but she could never find it again.

Comment: You say "Victorian house". Does that mean the story was set in the UK? If so, was it by a British author? Was it an illustrated book, or text only? Any detail wuld help.

Comment: [A Stitch in time](https://www.kelleyarmstrong.com/series/stitch/) but so far out of timeline and plot.

Comment: @Moriarty In the USA houses built 1837-1901 are also considered Victorian.